# Drag and Drop in WPF and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

i have three panels which holds three different user controls namely A, B and C.(note: these user controls are generated at runtime). the drag and drop from A to B and B to C forms a valid string in my application.

consider, A1, A2, A3 and A4 as instances of control A. and B1, B2, B3 and B4 as instances of control B and C1 and C2 as instances of control C.

consider, A1 is dragged and dropped on B1. which can then be dropped on C1 or C2. 
i want to restrict drag and drop behaviour of control B****(i mean, if i drop on B1 then i should be able to drag only B1 and not other instances)***.* currently, i can drag any instance irrespective of drop.

could any one give me some idea to achive the same?

Comment: When you start the drag detect which control you are dragging from, then on the drop detect what you are trying to drop onto, if it is a controll you dont want to allow just dont do any drop related code.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply but still it didnt work for me :( i could still drag the control the other control.

Comment: FOR SURE. code goes something like this:

Comment: FOR SURE. code goes something like this: the drop at Control B helps me get A also.  void B_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {  A usrA = e.Data.GetData(typeof(A)) as A;   B usrB = e.Source as B;  //identify the dropped(curently using a string) control                                              strCurrentConverter = usrB.Name; }  after being dragged B   void B_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e){ B cntB = sender as   B;}  trying to get sender at this point of time overrides the string that am using to identify the control on drop

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [sample](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=d8443a8832e1fdf8&resid=D8443A8832E1FDF8!137) project that i have created uses three different controls and you can drag and drop in any of them and if you want to learn more you can visit [WPFTutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) here int the sample project you can set drop target where ever you want to allow drop and if not you can set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your type "B" control that indicates it is available for future Drag and Drop operations.

```
private bool IsActiveDragSource { get; set; }
```

Add a handler to the "Drop" event of your type 'B' control which sets the "IsActiveDragSource" property to true

```
private void label_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     // Handle the drop from control A
     this.IsActiveDragSource = true;
}
```

In your MouseMove (or whatever [Drag Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx) event you have chosen) only instantiate the [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx) operation if your new property is set to true.

```
    private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsActiveDragSource)
        {
            // Initialize the drag drop operation
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```